# Find the probability that each of the 4 piles has exactly 3 hearts

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

*A deck of 48 playing cards has had all 4 kings removed so that it now only has 12 cards of each suit. The pack is randomly divided into 4 piles of 12 cards each. 
Events are as follows:
E1= first pile has exactly 3 hearts
E2= second pile has exactly 3 hearts
E3= third pile has exactly 3 hearts
E4= fourth pile has exactly 3 hearts*

*Find P(E1 n E2 n E3 n E4) 
(the probability that each pile has exactly three hearts)*

I’ve been stuck on this problem for a while. I know that the probability obviously decreases with each heart but don’t know how to throw the 4 piles into the mix (which must matter because otherwise its just the probability of pulling 12 hearts from the deck).

I know Bayes Theorem plays a role in this, as our professor gave us a hint to it (i’ll put it below), but not sure how to put all this information together. Would love a detailed step-by-step so I can understand the thought process!

*Hint: use Q5*
*...*
*Here is Q5* (which I also don’t know how to go about) :
*For events A, B, C and D show that*
*P(A n B n C n D) = P(A) P(B|A) P(C|AnB) P(AnBnC)*

Comment: What is Q5? Would that be unrevealed earlier problem # 5? Anyhow some clue about Q5 might generate more interest in your question. // Please consider adding a 'self study' tag. // Can you get P(A) for a start?

Comment: I added Q5 at the bottom (the proof for AnBnCnD). Basically leading us to believe that formula should be used. I got P(E1) the way described below, however when it comes to P(E2), which I assume is (9 3) (24 6) / (36 12) [sorry don’t know how to format it but i’m sure you understand], I’m not sure how to then find P(E1 n E2), in order to find P(E2 | E1), if that makes sense? Otherwise I’m definitely on the wrong track.

Comment: @G5W: D not needed. If three heaps each have exactly 3 hearts, then the 4th one must also.

Comment: okay that makes sense! i guess the only unanswered question i have left then is how to find either p(e2|e1) or p(e1ne2) as theyre dependent and i cant multiply them to get the intersection

Comment: That's were you need to use the Hint in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a nice homework problem on combinatorial methods and Bayes' Theorem.
So I don't want to give a complete combinatorial solution. But I thought
it would be fun to simulate an approximate answer in R, using a million shuffles.
The answer seems to be about 0.03354 (correct to 2 or 3 places).

```
set.seed(2020)
deck = rep(1:4, each=12)  # 1's are Hearts
m = 10^6; event = logical(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
  shuf = sample(deck)     # shuffle deck
  h.1 = sum(shuf[1:12]==1)  # numbers of 
  h.2 = sum(shuf[13:24]==1) #  hearts in
  h.3 = sum(shuf[25:36]==1) #   each of 4
  h.4 = sum(shuf[37:48]==1) #    heaps of 12
  event[i] = (h.1==3 & h.2==3 & h.3==3 & h.4==3)  # exactly 3 hearts in each 
  }
mean(event)
[1] 0.033538      # proportion of 'successes'
2*sd(event)/10^3
[1] 0.0003600735  # 95% margin of simulation error
```

*Note:* For exactly three hearts in the first heap of 12, the probability
is $\frac{{12\choose 3}{36\choose 9}}{{48 \choose 12}} \approx 0.2973$. Given that, what cards remain for the second heap? Etc.

```
dhyper(3,  12, 48-12,  12)
[1] 0.2972866
choose(12,3)*choose(36,9)/choose(48, 12)
[1] 0.2972866
```